# descartes, python package, error in polygonpatch

Tags: python, polygon, descartes

I have installed the latest Descartes package using pip3. But I cannot seem to run the example code provided in the [website](https://pypi.org/project/descartes/).

```
`

    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_500743/916321365.py in <module>
     20 
     21 dilated = line.buffer(0.5)
---> 22 patch1 = PolygonPatch(dilated, fc=BLUE, ec=BLUE, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
     23 ax.add_patch(patch1)
     24 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/descartes/patch.py in PolygonPatch(polygon, **kwargs)
     85 
     86     """
---> 87     return PathPatch(PolygonPath(polygon), **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/descartes/patch.py in PolygonPath(polygon)
     60                 "A polygon or multi-polygon representation is required")
     61 
---> 62     vertices = concatenate([
     63         concatenate([asarray(t.exterior.coords)[:, :2]] +
     64                     [asarray(r)[:, :2] for r in t.interiors])

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/descartes/patch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     62     vertices = concatenate([
     63         concatenate([asarray(t.exterior.coords)[:, :2]] +
---> 64                     [asarray(r)[:, :2] for r in t.interiors])
     65         for t in polygon])
     66     codes = concatenate([

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/descartes/patch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     62     vertices = concatenate([
     63         concatenate([asarray(t.exterior.coords)[:, :2]] +
---> 64                     [asarray(r)[:, :2] for r in t.interiors])
     65         for t in polygon])
     66     codes = concatenate([

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287534/indexerror-descartes-polygonpatch-wtih-shapely), I tried to apply the suggestions in that post, as you can see in the last few lines of the error, by simply changing

```
t.exterior
```

to

```
t.exterior.coords.
```

the error is not resolved. I have shapely version (2.0.1), and numpy (1.22.3) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip uninstall shapely
```

and

```
pip install shapely==1.8.5
```

Comment: Why should OP downgrade this library? Please read [answer].