# OSMnx isochrones PolygonPatch IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, distance, osmnx

I've been trying to use OSMnx to get isodistance for my project and follow the tutorial on
[Git](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v1.0.1/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb)

Yet, I'm stuct on this part

```
# plot the network then add isochrones as colored descartes polygon patches
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False, edge_color='#999999', edge_alpha=0.2, node_size=0)
for polygon, fc in zip(isochrone_polys, iso_colors):
    patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, fc=fc, ec='none', alpha=0.6, zorder=-1)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()
```

which give me

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287534/indexerror-descartes-polygonpatch-wtih-shapely) that the problem was caused by `shapely` changed how it handles Polygon exteriors and `descartes` simply hasn't been updated and the solution was to modify the installed `descartes`, but I was using `GoogleColab` which make that solution hard to implement.

Is there other solution or alternative ways to get isodistance from a point?

Comment: What is your `osmnx` version?

Comment: It's `osmnx 1.7.1`