# Drawing the outermost contour of a set of data points without losing resolution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, convex-hull

I have a set of data points (as scattered data points in black) and I want to draw their outermost contour. I have tried to calculate the convex hull of my points (code below)  but I lose too much resolution and the shape loses its nuances.

```
# load usual stuff
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import colors
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

# read input file
cbm_contour = sys.argv[1]


def parse_pdb_coords(file):
    f = open(file, "r")

    coords = X = np.empty(shape=[0, 3])

    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break

        if line.split()[0] == "ATOM" or line.split()[0] == "HETATM":
            Xcoord = float(line[30:38])
            Ycoord = float(line[38:46])
            Zcoord = float(line[46:54])

            coords = np.append(coords, [[Xcoord, Ycoord, Zcoord]], axis=0)

    return coords

##########################################################################

plt.figure(figsize=(11, 10))

# parse input file
cbm_coords = parse_pdb_coords(cbm_contour)

# consider only x- and y-axis coordinates
flattened_points = cbm_coords[:, :2]
x = cbm_coords[:,0]
y = cbm_coords[:,1]

# Find the convex hull of the flattened points
hull = ConvexHull(flattened_points)

for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(flattened_points[simplex, 0], flattened_points[simplex, 1], color='red', lw=2)

plt.scatter(cbm_coords[:,0], cbm_coords[:,1], s=1, c='black')

plt.xlabel('X-axis coordinate ($\mathrm{\AA} $)', size=16)
plt.ylabel('Y-axis distance ($\mathrm{\AA} $)', size=16)

plt.yticks(np.arange(-20, 24, 4),size=16)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-20, 24, 4),size=16)

plt.savefig("example.png", dpi=300, transparent=False)
plt.show()
```

Note that this can't be transformed to a 'minimal working example' due to the complexity of the data points, but my dataset can be downloaded [here](https://pastebin.com/5GWdqHQc). The idea is to have a generalized solution for other datasets too.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the data

Comment: @mozway I did my best to provide the necessary inputs to reproduce the example, but the result is dependent on the complex shape of the dataset, so the best I could do was to make the input dataset available via Pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [Alpha Shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) instead of your Convex Hull, for instance using the [`alphashape`](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) library.

You will have to test different values for `alpha` to find one that suits your needs. Here `alpha=1` did a good job.

```
# pip install alphashape
# pip install descartes

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alphashape import alphashape
from descartes import PolygonPatch

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1], s=1, color='k')
ax.set_aspect(1)

ashape = alphashape(arr[:, :2].tolist(), alpha=1)

ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(ashape, fc='none', ec='red'))
```

Output:

[image: pandas alpha shape]

Assuming such input as `arr` (X, Y, Z):

```
array([[-18.1  ,   1.418,   4.103],
       [-17.712,   2.202,   5.819],
       [-17.58 ,   1.998,   5.527],
       ...,
       [  9.472,  -1.901,  11.157],
       [  9.472,  -1.295,  11.615],
       [  9.472,  -0.895,  12.261]])
```

---

###### NOTE

If you get the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Then your version of `shapely` is too recent for `descartes`. You can fix the issue by following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405557/16343464).

Comment: Thank you @mozway. I have tried your solution, which seems great, but I am getting an error here with the PolygonPatch class:

  File "/home/mdpoleto/Documents/Softwares/anaconda3/envs/matplotlib/lib/python3.12/site-packages/descartes/patch.py", line 63, in PolygonPath
    concatenate([asarray(t.exterior)[:, :2]] +
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

I confirmed the shape of my input arr as (5097, 3), while the shape of the variable 'ashape' is (). Any thoughts?

Comment: @mdpoleto have you tried with different values of `alpha`? Did you test with the same dataset?

Comment: I found out the issue. Descartes has a bug that has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287534/indexerror-descartes-polygonpatch-wtih-shapely 

I ran their fix and the script works just fine now. Can you include that discussion in your answer? I will upvote it and mark as the correct answer.

Comment: @mdpoleto I'm happy to but I haven't had the issue myself (alphashape 1.3.1, descartes 1.1.0, shapely 1.8.5.post1). Feel free to edit my answer with additional details.